# Notice: Array to string conversion when echoing the array

Tags: php, arrays, class

IM getting the error

```
Notice: Array to string conversion php
```

by calling my array from a outside class.. can anybody spot the problem here

script home.php

```
echo b::addarray(123, sea, 1);//i tried this way,dint work either("123","sea","1")
die();
```

the script with the array

```
class b
{

    static function addarray($a,$b,$c){

        $red = array();
        array_push($red, $a,$b,$c);
        return $red;
    }
}
```

Comment: print_r(addarray(123, sea, 1)).try this now. and tell

Comment: You cannot echo an array, use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`. `echo` is used for strings and not arrays and objects.

Comment: If you get solution then mark one of them as an answer which is the most appropriate one for you.rest you can vote up if they are helpful also. it will help others to get the solution.

Comment: People are not interested in marking and up-voting the answer and telling problem is solved or not? Really frustrating. Wastage of effort. deleting my answer

Answer (score 4):

Try it as follows, as you were echoing an `array` you need to use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`

```
$re = new b();
$result = $re::addarray(123,'sea',1);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 3):

sea is a string ,it should be quoted.and try this

```
 <?php
        class b
    {

        static function addarray($a,$b,$c){

           static  $red = array();
            array_push($red, $a,$b,$c);
            return $red;
        }
        }


      print_r(b::addarray(123, "sea", 1));
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r(b::addarray(123, sea, 1));

  or

foreach(b::addarray(123, sea, 1) as $key=>$val) {

   echo $key."#".$val;

}
```

Comment: foreach Parenthesis not closed foreach(b::addarray(123, sea, 1) as $key=>$val) {echo $key."#".$val;

}